# How to reuse connection to amqp across the whole app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a problem with reusing of the connection to `amqp` in my express/typescript app.  Below is my code:

```
import * as amqp from "amqplib";

export const amqpConnection = async (): Promise<amqp.Channel> => {
    const connection = await amqp.connect("amqp://localhost");
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();

    return channel;
}

export const sendMessageToQueue = async (message: any) => {
    const channel = await amqpConnection();
    const msg = channel.sendToQueue("queue_name", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message)));
    console.log("sendMessageToQueue: ", message.id);
}
```

Right now I'm using function `amqpConnection` in which I create new channel and return this channel, connection is created on every time I launch `sendMessageToQueue` function, and I don't want it.

How to create reusable using of the connection or channel across the whole my express app?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am also looking for a good approach to do what you want exactly. DId you find anything by this time?